# Margins and paddings with Android native browser 4.1.2

Tags: android, html, css, android-browser

I'm having few interesting CSS observations with the native Android browser (Android v 4.1.2):

- For `main` tag all margins and paddings are ignored
- When margin or padding is specified in one line, like `margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px;` it will be rendered as `margin: 0px;`
- Padding values are largely ignored even when set like `padding-left: 10px`

This all is a bit frustrating, but the question is: how to specify margins for this old(ish) native Android browser so that they are behaving exactly the same way on other modern browsers?

Comment: Is it confirmed that this issue is only with that browser? Has it been tested fine on mobile safari, chrome, etc with no issues?

Comment: @tsHunter yes, no issues on modern mobile Chrome, iOS Safari, and even modern native Android browser behaves properly.